# How to disallow copy text from android app to keep corporate data as secured

Tags: android, android-enterprise, samsung-knox

We are working on a secure app in which we share secure data with corporate users. Since the data needs to be secured and the user shouldn't be able to copy the data.

The issue is, using Samsung Knox, we can disable copy-paste for all apps and also block clipboard sharing between apps(https://docs.samsungknox.com/devref/knox-sdk/reference/com/samsung/android/knox/restriction/RestrictionPolicy.html#allowClipboardShare(boolean))

but the issue is: this is not what we want.
What we need is: users should be able to copy text from our app and use it internally in our app. but the same copied data shouldn't be accessible to other apps. and text copied in another app should be accessible to our app.

mostly this app will be having web views.

Any options I can manage this? any mechanism we can implement our own copy-paste context menu or something?

Any inputs...??

Answer (score 0):

Android Enterprise has a policy that can limit clipboard sharing between the work and personal profile: [CrossProfileCopyPaste](https://developers.google.com/android/management/reference/rest/v1/enterprises.policies#crossprofilecopypaste).

It is not exactly what you are asking for because this will allow to use the same clipboard within the work profile, but you cannot copy content from the work profile to the personal one.

Comment: yes but we need this within the same profile, especially because of `Fully managed` mode

Answer (score 0):

Create SEAMS container on Samsung device and apply restriction for Clipboard share. This is same concept from Linux where apps are added to categories and we can define granular policies.
https://docs.samsungknox.com/dev/knox-sdk/container-seams.htm
https://docs.samsungknox.com/devref/knox-sdk/reference/com/samsung/android/knox/seams/SEAMSPolicy.html

While this have been deprecated since Android 30 its still working now and i hope Google shall provide similar policies in Android in future.